# Do I need 2 hosting services if I want to have a Rails RESTful API and an AngularJS2 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, rest, web-applications

As the question suggests, I'm planning to have separate web apps. One is purely AngularJS2 and the other is purely Rails RESTful API. Do I need 2 hosting services to support that? I'm currently trying out Heroku and it seems it can only deploy 1 project at a time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to host twice to get this done at all. I'm assuming one app is a web app, and the other is a mobile app, which will be accessing data from the API of your app. So you host your at Heroku, to support your web app, And configure your mobile app to make request calls to heroku hosted app's API to get resources.

Please provide more details, if this doesn't clarify.
Thanks.

Comment: Partly correct. I'm creating a (initially) frontend-less RESTful web app that only produces and consumes json through Rails. The other one is a full-blown front-end application made with AngularJS and runs with NodeJS. This is for both of them to be independent from each other, and teams can develop on their own.

Previously, Rails and AngularJS can be together with its asset pipeline. But with the introduction of AngularJS2, I think I'd better separate the two.

If my API is on Heroku, where can I host my other app?

Comment: So I assume, you will be accessing one database for both the apps. Its possible in heroku. But I recommend trying out AWS. It gives you complete flexibility, just as would get in a local machine.